# R Shiny App : button for downloading code

Tags: r, shiny

I know code can be embedded in a .rmd along with shiny app in it as below for example:

```
title: Flex Dashboard
author: Yeshy
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    self_contained: true
    social: ["twitter", "facebook"]
    #logo: Science1.JPG
    #favicon: favicon.png
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
```

Which outputs a button to access the whole .rmd code

[image]

But is there a way to share/download the code of a shiny app via a button?

Comment: why not just create a button and link it to repository ( github/bitbucket )?

Comment: I don't have a github repo yet. Might need to get down to that soon.

Comment: I think repository option will be nice if you want to share an open source software, another developer might happy to contribute it via PR. that's just my opinion. but if you just want to show the code from markdown, you can link those button to open new page and call includeMarkdown("include.md") from markdown library package.